# How to implement jQuery on Event with Jquery Plugin Elements

Tags: jquery

I want to implement jquery plugin element on Ajax Sucess request.

like

```
$(document).on('click','.someclass',function() {
//my code 
});
```

But now i have some functions

```
$('.nailthumb-container').nailthumb({width: 223, height: 147});
```

and

```
 $("div.recent_articles").smoothDivScroll({
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
        });
```

How to implement on event on Above Functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"some_url",  
    success:function(data) {
      $(document).on('click','.someclass',function() {
       // my code 
      });
    } 
});
```

Best read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i dont want to use that. As my plugin also calls on document load.

Comment: Still you are using on ajaxSucess.  why  click? also all functions i need on document ready function

Comment: That's just a sample on what you could do with the `$.ajax.success` event

Comment: i already mention you, i need to use that elements on document ready state also. i want to use .on method.